# Test a string if it's Unicode, which UTF standard is and get its length in bytes?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, python-2.5

I need to test if a string is Unicode, and then if it whether it's UTF-8. After that, get the string's length in bytes including the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), if it ever uses that. How can this be done in Python?

Also for didactic purposes, what does a byte list representation of a UTF-8 string look like? I am curious how a UTF-8 string is represented in Python.

Latter edit: pprint does that pretty well.

Comment: What encodings are you expecting the string to be in?

Comment: I need them to be UTF8 and ASCII!

Comment: If the string is ASCII, then it is also in UTF-8. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I get the relative path of a file in a zip with zipfile library and I need to see if it is according to this standard:http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/#zip-relative-paths

Comment: In that case, all you need is to test whether it is UTF-8.

Comment: @ecatmur and if it has only ASCII characters ? How can I know it ?

Comment: You can write `string.decode('ascii')`, but there's not much point, as ASCII is valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
try:
    string.decode('utf-8')
    print "string is UTF-8, length %d bytes" % len(string)
except UnicodeError:
    print "string is not UTF-8"
```

In Python 2, `str` is a sequence of bytes and `unicode` is a sequence of characters.  You use `str.decode` to decode a byte sequence to `unicode`, and `unicode.encode` to encode a sequence of characters to `str`.  So for example, `u"é"` is the unicode string containing the single character U+00E9 and can also be written `u"\xe9"`; encoding into UTF-8 gives the byte sequence `"\xc3\xa9"`.

In Python 3, this is changed; `bytes` is a sequence of bytes and `str` is a sequence of characters.

Comment: I want to see also if string is ASCII or Unicode, your code doesn't take the possibility for the string being other type of UTF unicode?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu for other encodings, pass another encoding to `string.decode`.

Comment: I get this error on string.decode('utf-8') `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu in that case `string` is already a `unicode` object, so it's a sequence of characters, not bytes.  You can check how many bytes its UTF-8 representation uses with `len(string.encode('utf-8'))`.

Comment: It seems that a `zipfile` library `Zipinfo` object has a hidden field: `orig_filename` other that `filename` which is already unicode that contains the original encoding of the filename in my case UTF8.

Answer (score 8):

To Check if Unicode

```
>>>a = u'F'
>>>isinstance(a, unicode)
True
```

To Check if it is UTF-8 or ASCII

```
>>>import chardet
>>>encoding = chardet.detect('AA')
>>>encoding['encoding']
'ascii'
```

Comment: With instance I get a lot of this: `UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal ` and with the second if I put in place of ('AA') I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Answer (score 7):

I would definitely recommend Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know about Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), if you haven't already read it.

For Python's Unicode and encoding/decoding machinery, start [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html). To get the byte-length of a Unicode string encoded in utf-8, you could do:

```
print len(my_unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

Your question is tagged python-2.5, but be aware that this changes somewhat in Python 3+.