# web2py windows-linux interoperability

Tags: python, web2py

I have a system which I have developed in Web2py framework on Windows machine and now it is deployed on Linux machine. In this system I check type of input data for **Unicode** and if it is not it returns error message as **Unicode** is required. I send parameters to it as `u'HI'` or `unicode('HELLO')`. This worked on my Windows machine but now as I have deployed the system on Linux I am getting error as Unicode is required. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

I have same verion of Python(2.7.2) on both machines.

This is how I am checking type of input variable:

```
if isinstance(value,getattr(__builtin__,'unicode')) or isinstance(value,unicode)):                    
    pass
else:
    return "error message"
```

I have tried following commands on my machine and linux server to check for python encoding settings. Its results are as given below:

My Machine-

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
cp1252
>>> print sys.stdin.encoding
cp1252
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>>
```

On Linux machine

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8
>>> print sys.stdin.encoding
UTF-8
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>>
```

Do I need to change encoding settings at any of the machines in order to fix this?

Comment: Can you show some relevant code, input and output? Are you using same Python version in both OS?

Comment: @PauloBu Just edited the question.

Comment: I think you're not giving enough information in the question for us to answer it. It is unclear how you pass through the input for example.

Comment: @PauloBu It is a JSON web service which is developed using web2py server. I am trying to access that service using jsonrpclib from my Windows machine. I am passing it data in Unicode (ex: user_ip_address=unicode('10.253.152.71')). Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: JSON handles the Unicode details. Please state your *specific* problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am passing a dictionary which has various keys whose values are unicode strings from my Windows machine. The request hits my Linux server and there I get that dictionary but the values are not unicode, their type is str. In my code it doesn't go ahead unless the type is Unicode. However when I send the data to other Windows machine, the values are in Unicode and it works.

Comment: That sounds less like an interoperability issue and more a problem with the service and/or web2py itself.

Answer (score 1):

If possible usually [avoid directly type-checking](http://sayspy.blogspot.jp/2008/12/why-explicit-type-checking-is-mostly.html) variables - just use them. Here is [an example that does it with try-except](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053219/377366).

Would it be invalid to try coercing your inputs before completely discarding them? For example if your linux system is passing in ascii strings, why not just convert them to utf-8?

```
try:
    value = value.decode('utf-8')
except (SyntaxError, AttributeError):  # I would probably just do Exception to catch all
    return "error message"
```

If that doesn't solve it, then could you do some investigation into the exact inputs you are receiving in windows and on linux and also explain why coercing won't work for you?