# Comparing UTF8 strings in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I want to check that if the argumant *s* of function *f1(s)* receives some strings (that are in UTF8 ) in *MyList* then call function *f2*; But I cannot compare strings correctly.

```
def f1( s ):
    MyList = [ u"نامشخص".encode("utf-8") , u"Unknow".encode("utf-8")]
    for t in MyList:
        if( t == s.encode('utf-8') ):
            f2()
            return None
            break
        else:
            print "Checked strings: ",  t , " =?=" , s.encode("utf-8")
            print "Checked strings length: ", len(t),  " =?=" , len(s)
    return s
```

Checking:

```
MyList2 = [ u"نامشخص" , "test2".encode("utf-8"), u"نامشخص".encode("utf-8") ]

for a in MyList2:
    print "Test String = ", a
    f1(a)
    print "\n\n"
```

Output:

```
 Test String =  نامشخص
 Here[=]



Test String =  test2
Checked strings:  نامشخص  =?= test2
Checked strings length:  12  =?= 5

Checked strings:  Unknow  =?= test2
Checked strings length:  6  =?= 5



Test String =  نامشخص
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    f1(a)
  File "test.py", line 18, in f1
    if( t == s.encode('utf-8') ):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Infact I receive string *s* from sqlite db and I don't know the encoding of *s*. 
It is intersting that for some string *s* from db *f1* mistakes without error!
It seems *f1* works only for some specified encodings. Is there any solution that works for all encoding for string *s*?

Comment: Can you post your output and your tests ? It works for me without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think python don't like the double `.encode("utf-8")`. This script make the same issue :

```
a = u"نامشخص"
b = a.encode("utf-8")  # This work !
c = b.encode("utf-8")  # Not that.
```

You can use a try/except to handle this issue (see: [Test a string if it's Unicode, which UTF standard is and get its length in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053107/test-a-string-if-its-unicode-which-utf-standard-is-and-get-its-length-in-bytes))

This can be a solution :

```
def get_unicode(s):
    try:
        return s.encode("utf-8")
    except:
        return s
```

Edit : maybe a better test :

```
def get_unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s.encode("utf-8")
    return s
```

Comment: Your answer gives me an idea. In fact I receive string s from sqlite db and I don't know the encoding of _s_. For some string _s_ from db _f1_ STILL makes mistakes without any error! I will try to extend your function to solve this issue. Thank you!